# How to add string value at the end of Base Address using HttpClientFactory?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

I'm using HttpClientFactory to make http requests.

Here's my code : -

```
namespace handleDeviceOperations
{
    
class Program
{

string operationID = String.Empty;
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
    var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var httpClientFactory = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();

    //Getting operationID from few other lines of code

    var httpClientGetOperations = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("getOperations");
    var request1 = await httpClientGetOperations.GetAsync("");
    var responseMessage1 = await request1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
private static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddHttpClient("getOperations", options =>
    {
        options.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myurl.com/events/");

        options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic","Auth_Value");
    });   
}
}
```

As you can see this is my Base Address : `"https://myurl.com/events/"`
Now, just before making the request here : -

```
var httpClientGetOperations = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("getOperations");
var request1 = await httpClientGetOperations.GetAsync("");
```

I want to add the operationID to the end of the Base Address such that the Base Address becomes something like this : -

```
"https://myurl.com/events/45872254"
//The string at the end will differ each time
```

This is a very necessary step as the request is completely dependent on the operationID parameter.

Comment: If it will change every time, could you not just append it to the request each time, like this? `GetAsync($"{operationID}?parameters")`

Comment: How to do that exactly?

Comment: @zep426 Oh okay got it. Similar to how Andrii has explained in his answer, right?

Comment: Yes, that would have been my answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
options.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myurl.com/");
...
var id = 45872254;
var request1 = await httpClientGetOperations.GetAsync($"events/{id}");
```